# What value should Apache 2.4 environment variable CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT contain?

Tags: perl, apache, environment-variables

A recent update from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 on GoDaddy has caused my Perl scripts to malfunction. This is a shared hosting environment. I've been talking to GoDaddy tech support to no avail, and have looked through everything I can find at the Apache Foundation, Google searches, and here for some help but have come up empty. I have 2 websites, one is a subdomain. My Perl scrips look for an environment variable (SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT) that in the 2.2 server was set if a requested URL was in the subdomain, and not set otherwise. In either case DOCUMENT_ROOT was set to the top of the primary domain. Once the script determined its context it would look for appropriate data files.

After the Apache 2.4 update, the SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT variable has disappeared. A new variable, CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT, is now in the environment. However, it always points to the top of the primary domain regardless of whether the invoked script is in the primary domain or the subdomain. I have found virtually no documentation on CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT except  the following:

Revision 1132494
Author: sf
Date: Sun Jun 5 21:33:12 2011 UTC (2 years, 1 month ago)
Changed paths: 11
Log Message:
- Introduce concept of context prefix (which is an URL prefix) and context document root (which is the file system directory that this URL prefix is mapped to). This generalization of the document root makes it easier for scripts to create self-referential URLs and to find their files.
- Expose CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT and CONTEXT_PREFIX as envvars, in mod_rewrite, and in ap_expr.
- Make mod_alias and mod_userdir set the context information.
- Allow to override the document root on a per-request basis. This allows mass vhosting modules to set DOCUMENT_ROOT correctly.
- Make mod_vhost_alias set the per-request document root

This sounds to me to mean that CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT should point to the top of the subdomain tree if the requested URL is in the subdomain. If that is so, the GoDaddy installation is broken. They say it's not. Can anyone point me to definitive documentation of CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT, preferably with an example or two?

Comment: May be covered here (recent): http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/subdomain_document_root-in-php/

Comment: @ashley - Interesting... REAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT appears in the environment available to php and is set correctly, but it's not in the environment available to Perl. I'll try to bounce this off GoDaddy support. The php environment also contains CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT, but it's set to the primary domain as it is for Perl.